# how to make a block of selected text become code

Tags: support, code-formatting

Is there a way to drag my mouse over some text to select it and then press a button to have it get spaced in 4 spaces so I don't have to manually do it over long blocks of text.  It has become somewhat tedious.

Comment: Select the text and click the `{}` button on the toolbar, or use the keyboard shortcut for your platform (see linked post).

Comment: You can select the code and then press `ctrl+k`

Answer (score 3):

You can press the `{}` button once you selected some text. It will automatically add the spaces.

[image]

Comment: +1 freehand drawing.

Comment: @TronicZomB +1 for appreciating my paint skillz

Answer (score 0):

It is the fifth button over at the top that looks like -> { }